# Magento 2: How to get resize image for Custom Module?

Tags: magento2, image, image-upload, image-preview

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

I have Custom Module with Image Field. When it's uploaded, i want different size images as for product we have
Thumbnail Image, List Image & Product Detail Page Image.

Able to upload 1 image without resize.

I'm using below code for resizing image, but it's giving product image URL. Not my custom module.

\app\code\Custom\Module\Block\MyPosts\Edit.php

```
public function getImage($posts, $image) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    echo $postImage = $_imagehelper->init($posts, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
    exit;
}
```

It gives below URL http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg

My image is stored here: `\magento2\pub\media\custom_module\posts\image`.

How can i get resize image with this path & how can i save/retrieve different size image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check in details by click, [Resize Custom Image in Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/resize-custom-image-in-magento-2/)

Inside Block file keep below code,

```
   protected $_filesystem ;
   protected $_imageFactory;
   public function __construct(            
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         
        ) {         
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;         
        }

    // pass imagename, width and height
    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;
        if (!file_exists($absolutePath)) return false;
        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;
        if (!file_exists($imageResized)) { // Only resize image if not already exists.
            //create image factory...
            $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
            $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
            $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
            $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
            //destination folder                
            $destination = $imageResized ;    
            //save image      
            $imageResize->save($destination);         
        } 
        $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
        return $resizedURL;
  }
```

Now Call inside phtml file,

```
$block->resize('test.jpg',500,400);
```

Comment: Bravo. Works perfectly. So while Add Image we don't have to upload with different sizes. Only while displaying we have to manage correct @Rakesh?

Comment: yes when we have to display at that time manage.

Comment: doesn't work when we try to resize 1 image and put it in same folder with same image same.
like this :
$absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getRelativePath('C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/Aht/BannerSlider/view/frontend/web/').$image;

        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getRelativePath('C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/Aht/BannerSlider/view/frontend/web/').$image;

Comment: As already mentioned, this should not be the accepted answer. You do not need to do all this yourself - simply use the already existing image helper of the Magento core.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya,its giving me unknown text as a url

Comment: I am getting this error Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /magento\/framework\/Image\/Adapter\/AbstractAdapter.php on line 305"

Comment: I am getting above error only in actual server, in local it is working, I have tried by adding @getimagesize() but then getting error then image type is unsupported.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer doesn’t consider caching the image to improve performance. You don’t need to resize and overwrite the image every time it’s requested. The following approach saves the resized image to a "cache" folder so successive calls return the image from the cache. The method is contained on a helper (not a block) so you can call it from any template you like:

app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Helper/Image.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Custom directory relative to the "media" folder
     */
    const DIRECTORY = 'custom_module/posts';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $_mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory
     */
    protected $_imageFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory $imageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * First check this file on FS
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _fileExists($filename)
    {
        if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($filename)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Resize image
     * @return string
     */
    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $mediaFolder = self::DIRECTORY;

        $path = $mediaFolder . '/cache';
        if ($width !== null) {
            $path .= '/' . $width . 'x';
            if ($height !== null) {
                $path .= $height ;
            }
        }

        $absolutePath = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($mediaFolder) . $image;
        $imageResized = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path) . $image;

        if (!$this->_fileExists($path . $image)) {
            $imageFactory = $this->_imageFactory->create();
            $imageFactory->open($absolutePath);
            $imageFactory->constrainOnly(true);
            $imageFactory->keepTransparency(true);
            $imageFactory->keepFrame(true);
            $imageFactory->keepAspectRatio(true);
            $imageFactory->resize($width, $height);
            $imageFactory->save($imageResized);
        }

        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path . $image;
    }
}
```

Now from any .phtml template you can call the method like this:

```
<!-- Get a reference to the Image helper -->
<?php $image = $this->helper('Vendor\Namespace\Helper\Image'); ?>
.
.
.
<!-- Resize the image by specifying width only -->
<img src="<?php echo $image->resize('/my-picture.jpg', 1200); ?>">

<!-- Resize the image by specifying width and height -->
<img src="<?php echo $image->resize('/my-picture.jpg', 640, 480); ?>">
```

Comment: May I suggest adding a check for the original file, in case that it doesn't exist? in the resize() function: I changed `if (!$this->_fileExists($path . $image)) {` to `if (!$this->_fileExists($path . $image) && $this->_fileExists($mediaFolder . $image)) {`

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks you. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: You can also simply use the existing `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`.

Comment: @fritzmg isn't this helper only intended for product images? How can I use it with custom image which is not a product image but image uploaded with custom module to /pub/media folder and has no relation to product?

Comment: Yeah you are right - it would only work for product images, my mistake :)

Comment: @kovinet - It works with any image as long as the original image is contained within the pub/media/ folder. Just pass the path of the image to $image->resize('image/path/filename.ext');

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you don't need to create new classes for resizing your images, since Magento helpers already have it (see `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::resize`).

So, you can just do:

```
$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

echo $_imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('65','65')->getUrl();
```

You can also see an example of this usage at `\Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Merchandiser\Tile::getImageUrl` (Magento EE only I guess)

Comment: But your example would only work with product images, right? The question is about custom module with Image field. So there is no `$product` but only path to the image file in /media.

Comment: You are right @kovinet. I didn't notice it at that time. However, this thread helped me with product images, and it seems its helping others. But thank you for your comment. As soon I have some time, I'll look for a better answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered an issue where the `resize` method wouldn't crop the image to my dimensions so you need to calculate the crop values from top and bottom or left and right, depending on your original image size. I used the code from @Rakesh and modified it so it checks whether the original image is taller or wider and crops accordingly:

```
public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
{
    $mediaFolder = self::DIRECTORY;

    $path = $mediaFolder . 'cache';
    if ($width !== null) {
        $path .= '/' . $width . 'x';
        if ($height !== null) {
            $path .= $height ;
        }
    }

    $absolutePath = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($mediaFolder) . $image;
    $imageResized = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path) . $image;

    if (!$this->_fileExists($path . $image) && $this->_fileExists($mediaFolder . $image)) {
        $imageFactory = $this->_imageFactory->create();
        $imageFactory->open($absolutePath);
        $imageFactory->constrainOnly(true);
        $imageFactory->keepAspectRatio(true);
        $imageFactory->keepFrame(false);

        $originalWidth = $imageFactory->getOriginalWidth();
        $originalHeight = $imageFactory->getOriginalHeight();

        $oldAspectRatio = $originalWidth / $originalHeight;
        $newAspectRatio = $width / $height;

        if ($oldAspectRatio > $newAspectRatio) {
            // original image is wider than the desired dimensions
            $imageFactory->resize(null, $height);
            $crop = ($imageFactory->getOriginalWidth() - $width) / 2;
            $imageFactory->crop(0, $crop, $crop, 0);
        } else {
            // it's taller...
            $imageFactory->resize($width, null);
            $crop = ($imageFactory->getOriginalHeight() - $height) / 2;
            $imageFactory->crop($crop, 0, 0, $crop);
        }

        $imageFactory->save($imageResized);

    }

    return $this->_storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path . $image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Rakesh -- I have done same but it is not working for me there is an error

> Blockquote Error filtering template: Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/sitename/pub/media/onecategory/6/7/671471390.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/sitename/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php on line 304

can you help me in this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you find the solution? Because i'm in your situation now. :(

Comment: please check folder or file permission.

Comment: doesn't have folder Aht_BannerSlider/images/slide_1.jpg in C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/media/Aht_BannerSlider/images/slide_1.jpg, And also i have just give the permission for the pub folder.

Comment: And still doesn't work. :(

Comment: please check last answer on this page.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm following it and get this issue tho :) But i got this :) Thanks for help