# Magento version 2.1.0 : Issue with static content deploy as not generating the product images

Tags: magento-2.1

I am running static content deployment command but unfortunately its not generating the media in pub folder 
**Magento version 2.1.0**

Comment: Is **.htaccess** file exist in your `pub/media/` folder ?

Comment: no .htaccess file in  pub/media./

Comment: that's the reason. Put .htaccess file from default magento.

Comment: but I have deleted the pub  folder and regenerating it .

Comment: never delete the whole pub folder. .htaccess file is not recoverable. Now you  have to download .htaccess file and paste it into pub folder. You can check my answer below .

Comment: got the folder but not the images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66934/discussion-between-user2428249-and-dinesh-yadav).

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: Using magento 2.1.0

Comment: add the image of your front end with your question

Answer (score 0):

**Static content deploy comment does not generate cache catalog image.** *Only geneses static  content means css , js html ,less.*

For generate cache  images you should use

> `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Comment: then how to fix the image issue as not catalog images are generating

Comment: You need do  custom code  and also check file permission

Comment: Please check  @rakesh blog  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/magento-2-how-to-get-resize-image-for-custom-module for generate resize image

Comment: your command doesn't worked

Comment: @amrit bera do you have any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Put **.htaccess** file from this url in your **pub/media** folder

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/pub/media/.htaccess