# Magento 2 product image custom resize

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-images, custom

I have created custom attribute for featured product and fetched the product collection using object manager.

```
 <?php 
 $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
 $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

  $collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('newest_product',['eq'=>1])
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
  ->load();

   foreach ($collection as $product) 
  {
    $pdata = $product->getData();   
    $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
    $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

 }
 ?>
```

Here $imageUrl Returns the full image of the Product while I want the image of **300X400**

I am trying to get the **300X400** size image in `$imageurl` code but not sure how to get the resized image. If you see the code, I have not used the helper method.

Need help to resize the product image to **300X400**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/magento-2-how-to-get-resize-image-for-custom-module

Comment: Thanks for your message.  I am using object manger method not factory method.  Also, not developed custom module for this.  i have created custom template file and called it in cms page.

Comment: I have used object manger.  Is it standard way to do this or i need to use factory method?  Perfomance is my main concern so which method i should use?

Comment: Check link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-resize-product-image-in-magento-2/