# resize image without loss quality in magento 2

Tags: magento2, image, image-resizing

I want to resize image without loss quality in magento 2
i used code

```
 $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();
 $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
 $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);
 $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);
 $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);
 $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
 $imageResize->resize($width, $height);
    //destination folder                
 $destination = $imageResized;
    //save image    
 $imageResize->save($destination);
```

when i resize it reduce the quality of image as compare to original image. 
How can i resize without losing quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize product image using below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');﻿
$productImageHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');﻿

$productId = 1; ///  change your product ID
$width = 150; /// Change as per your requirement
$height = 150; /// Change as per your requirement
$image_type = 'thumbnail';

$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
$resizedImage = $productImageHelper->init($product, $image_type)
                                   ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                   ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                   ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                                   ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                   ->resize($width, $height);
```

Comment: Hi @Darsh,
Thanks for answer but i cant resize product image i resize Instagram images that i get from curl. How can know i maintain quality of images.

Comment: For that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/magento-2-how-to-get-resize-image-for-custom-module post might help you.